# How to identify error [cdep] in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It's glad to ask, if can be reference to the other next time.
At this time (4 March 2015) use angularjs 1.4.0 beta 1 and i got this error 
when trying make `blocks.states` module like in [johnpapa demo](https://github.com/johnpapa/ng-demos/tree/master/modular/src/client/app/blocks), to replace the `blocks.router` while use [angular-toastr](https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr) too , the [official error doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/cdep) not help me in this case

```
$exceptionHandler <- $$q <- $animate <- toastr <- logger <- $exceptionHandler <- $rootScope <- $location <- statehelper
```

#### my question is

```
how to edentify that stack?
```

from left to right or right to left

or there are another solution to find the problem? my main question is that because i am insist to keep digging and learning angular and javascript. Any reference will be appriciated

Comment: That is showing you the dependency chain, so the arrow is showing what is dependent on what. `$exceptionHandler` seems to be dependent on `logger` etc. etc. which finally depends on `$exceptionHandler`, but as you can seen `$exceptionHandler` has that dependency chain, thus casuing and infinite loop of dependency resolution. Your issue it seems is that you're passing in the `$exceptionHandler` to another service as well as passing `logger`. You should pass in either one of the other

Comment: perhaps, i will check it, but the stack is confusing. what's $$q on there?

Comment: Something that `$animate` is depending on. need to see your dependencies and injections to find the issue.

Comment: it's seem the problem in this section ````angular
        .module('blocks.states')
        .factory('statehelper',statehelper);
    statehelper.$inject = ['$location', '$rootScope', 'logger', 'statehelperConfig','$injector'];````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the official doc:

> This error occurs when the `$injector` tries to get a service that depends on **itself**, either directly or indirectly.

Q: from left to right or right to left?

A: See the arrow, it's clearly from right to left, and that is also how identify that.

Let me give an example when you hit the [unpr](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr), and yell like so:

```
Unknown provider: loggerProvider <- logger <- loc
```

That indicates your `loc` things is depen on logger, so

> To fix that, make sure the dependency is **defined** and **spelled correctly**.

Thanks to [Callum Linington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1330137/callum-linington)

For future reference on javascript stack, you can watch [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6MXRNXXgP_0) by Philip Roberts on Scotland Js 9-10 May 2014